# How do I connect my new bathroom exhaust fan to the old duct that isn't lined up for the new fan?

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

The old fan died, and I'm trying to install a replacement. The old one was 80CFM, and, despite it working 24x7, the groundfloor bathroom was always a little damp.

The new one is a [fancy Panasonic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QYQWT3J), rated 110CFM and with a humidity sensor too, so far so good.

However, installing proves difficult:

- The existing exhaust air duct is 4" and was connected *directly* to the dead fan -- without the flexible part at the end. It protrudes right up to the edge of the fan's body -- the original installer worked before the sheetrock was installed...
- The new fan's opening is several inches to the side compared to the old one -- not where the existing air duct terminates.
- The duct is less than 15 feet long (vents to the wall) and rigid. It is attached to an aluminum strip half way through to the vent with a screw, which makes it impossible for me to force it far enough to the side to connect to the new fan.
- I cannot reach that aluminum strip -- and the screw -- without opening up the ceiling, which I loath doing. I can *see* it, if I stick my head between the joists in the fan-cavity, but I cannot *reach* it from there.
- It is tempting, since I'm messing with it all anyway, to also replace the 4" airduct with a 6" one. There is plenty of space between the joists for it, and the fan's own opening is 6" (it comes with a 6-to-4 reducer, which I don't have to use).

*I think* my options are:

1. Open up the vent cover on the outside -- the location is easy to reach from the ground -- and try using some tool on a long handle to either snap or saw the aluminum strip holding the existing duct (or the screw itself). Then -- pull the pipe out through the vent hole so it can be either replaced altogether (with a 6" one), or shortened. I'll then be able to add a 2'-long flexible sleeve to make it easy to connect to the new fan.
2. Try cutting away about 1' of the existing pipe on the inside, so that there is room to add the flexible sleeve. This would have to be done through the existing cavity (left by removal of the old fan). I can only squeeze one hand through that and will have to work blind...

Questions:

- Are there tools, that would help me with either approach? For the 1st one, for example, I thought of getting a [long-reach garden pruner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006ERQZKW) to saw at the aluminum strip (or the screw itself) -- maybe, after replacing the blade with a metal-rated one. Is there something better? For the 2nd, what can be used to cut the pipe *in situ* -- with one hand?
- Will installing a wider pipe really be beneficial -- or am I overrating the advantage of using a 6" exhaust compared to 4" one?
- If I do decide to widen the airduct -- what's the simplest way to widen the hole in the siding (HardiePlank)?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the screw oriented so that you could get to it with a loooong bit (extension) on a drill? Could you get to it with a 90° angle head on the extension? A mirror and a light on a stick ---would---, ---should---, _might_ let you see what you're doing in there.

Comment: No, the screw is vertical -- its head facing down (towards the bathroom's ceiling below it). I made a typo -- the duct is under 15 (not 5) total in length.

Comment: Something like [this 90° bit adapter](https://www.amazon.com/DEWALT-Right-Angle-Attachment-Impact/dp/B07NQS465R/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=90+degree+drill+adapter&qid=1593192652&sr=8-3) might let you get to the screw. **BUT** it can require 2 hands to work it - one to hold the drill, one to hold the bit in place. Might be worth a shot... How far away is the screw?

Comment: Not a chance :( This adapter is less than 1' long -- whereas the screw is about 7' feet away from either end of the duct... I don't think, it can be unscrewed without opening the ceiling -- but, maybe, it can be sawed or snapped off...

Comment: Worth a shot, and a new toy, er... tool is always nice. :) And they make extensions that you could put it on, but yeah, 7' is a bit much...